# Prevent overflowing characters from entering input buffer when using fgets in C

Tags: c

When the user input is larger than the buffer size specified to `fgets()`, the excess characters after then seem to be stored in the input buffer. When I call `fgets()` again, it reads those excess characters from the input buffer as the user input. Example code:

```
int main()
{
    char input[3];
    int input_int;
    
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter input: ");
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
        getchar();

        input_int = atoi(input);
        printf("Your input: %d\n", input_int);

        if (input_int == 100)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Example output (all in the same loop of the program):

```
Enter input: 12
Your input: 12

Enter input: 150
Your input: 15

Enter input: 32
Your input: 0

Enter input: 52
Your input: 2

Enter input: 8
Your input: 2

Enter input: 1
Your input: 0
```

How can I fix this behavior?

Comment: It's a bad habit to use puny buffers like `char[3]`. Instead consider using `char[255]` as a default, enabling you to deal with reasonable amounts of overflow.

Comment: In the example you give, the input stream is `12\n150\n32\n52\n8\n1\n`  Each call to fgets consumes at most 2 characters.  So the first call consumes `12`.  Then getchar() consumes `\n`.  The fgets consumes `15`.  Then `getchar()` consumes `0`.  fgets() then reads just a newline, and atoi() returns 0.  Stop using `getchar` to try to consume the newline.  If you do that and expect that `getchar` is consuming a newline, check that it does instead of just assuming it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell So `fgets()` is adding a newline after `getchar()` consumes the first overflow character?

Comment: Or rather, is it that `getchar()` is reading the first character that was added to the buffer? With the stream `150\n`, the buffer contains `0\n`, and since `0` is the first character, it gets eaten by `getchar()` first?

Comment: What do you mean by "overflow character"?  `fgets` reads up to 2 characters from the stream.  `getchar` consumes exactly 1.  When the input stream is `150\n`, fgets reads the first 2 (`15`), and getchar reads the next one `0`.  Now the next character in the stream is `\n`.  fgets reads from the stream and stops when it consumes 2 characters or reads a `\n`.

Comment: By "overflow characters", I mean the characters that aren't consumed by `fgets` since they would take it over its specified buffer size. It looks like I misunderstood which character from the stream `getchar` consumes as I thought it would take the last one to be added to the stream (`\n`) instead of the first to be added (`0`). Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's `fgets`'s job to *read* a *line*.  Not part of a line.  It's not `fgets`'s job to limit the line length if the line is too long.  The reason you supply the buffer size as the second argument to `fgets` is so that it can avoid a buffer overfow.

Comment: You should allocate a buffer (and pass the second argument to `fgets`) of a size that is *larger than you expect the user will ever type*.  Not the size the user is supposed to type, but the size the user might ever type.

Comment: If `fgets` fails to read the newline (meaning that there's a fraction of a line still sitting on the input stream, waiting to be read) it means that *something has gone wrong*.  Not as bad as a buffer overflow, but still wrong.  Either it means the buffer wasn't big enough after all, or you've got a malicious user who is trying to cause trouble.  But it's not a case that should be happening in normal, day-to-day use.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a larger buffer, however you could consume the leftover characters using `getchar()` if there is no `'\n'` character in your buffer, fgets doesn't consume the newline character, instead it saves it if there is space available. Like so:

```
if (strchr(input,'\n') == NULL) /* no occurence of the newline character in the buffer */
{
  while (getchar() != '\n')
    ;
}
```

Comment: This loop will fail if the input is closed

Comment: `while (getchar() != '\n');` -->  Infinite loop on end-of-file.